# Add Fake Category in Product Url Slug, like www.example.com/fake/myproduct.html

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

how it is possible to keep a forward slash in the product url slug? Everytime Magento changes the "/" to "-", but we need a fake subpath for robots.txt rules for certain products. We cant use category path mechanic, because only some products need this special urls.